# React Call back Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, asynchronous, callback

I have a handle Save function in a component which calls a function called savePDFNOW. I import this function from a different file I have made called reactToPdfUtils. After the function is done, which in this case is a pdf, I'd like to send word back to the component and change the state and render a success message.

I've been doing some research and trying to fumble through creating a call back function but can't seem to get it right or know if that is exactly what I need here.

```js
//passportMaker.jsx
var reactToPdfUtils = require('../reactToPdfUtils/reactToPdf.js');



    handleSave = (sourceElement, willSaveToDB, pageTemplate) => {
        console.log('handleSave called in passportMaker!');
        reactToPdfUtils.savePDFNOW(sourceElement, willSaveToDB, pageTemplate)
    };
    
    
    

    
    
    
//reactToPdf.js

export const savePDFNOW = (sourceElement, willSaveToDB, pageTemplate) => {
    //do all the stuff to make your pdf perfect
    //send word back to passportMaker that it is done
};
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to utilize [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try callback like this:-

```
var reactToPdfUtils = require('../reactToPdfUtils/reactToPdf.js');


    handleSave = (sourceElement, willSaveToDB, pageTemplate) => {
        console.log('handleSave called in passportMaker!');
        reactToPdfUtils.savePDFNOW(sourceElement, willSaveToDB, pageTemplate,fn)
    };
fn=(sendDataContent)=>{
// do your stuff with data 
}
    
//reactToPdf.js

export const savePDFNOW = (sourceElement, willSaveToDB, pageTemplate,callBackfn) => {
    //do all the stuff to make your pdf perfect
    //send word back to passportMaker that it is done
    callBackfn(sendDataContent);
};
```